# How do I control attributes in shader from separate game object's position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the lovely AdultLink Sphere Dissolve shader found here: https://unitylist.com/p/gh2/Sphere-Dissolve

The location of the dissolve is driven within the shader attribute from 3 position values.

I'd like to have those position values driven by a separate game object, but am a but if a noob so am not sure how to approach this.

(example, so a sphere could act as a controller)

Comment: It would seem to me that this is as simple as assigning the sphere object to some inspector field. Have you checked the asset's documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and change property name in a shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922082/find-and-change-property-name-in-a-shader)